# Node address in Infinispan

Tags: infinispan

I start up an infinispan cache which joins to a cluster. It is the only cache in the cluster.

Now, I connect using JMX to see what ports are being used.

I click on:

```
CacheManager / MyCache/ CacheManager/ Attributes
```

Under clusterMembers, I see [mymachine-54202]

Thinking 54202 is the port, I do both a

```
lsof -i udp
lsof -i tcp
```

I am on a mac and I can't see anything on 54202.  What does 54202 correspond to then?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a random number to differentiate between multiple caches running on the same box.

For more details, see http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/5.0/apidocs/config.html#ce_global_transport